# How can I store database locally in flutter for read only access?

Tags: android, ios, database, flutter, dart

I have constant data that would be delivered with the app source and won't be changing in the future. Data size is few tables each +/- 1000 row x 20 columns. How can I store them in the app?

I should have the option to the filter data on several layers, like filtering table rows by certain value of column, and then further filter the rows by certain values of other column.

How can I load certain table asynchronously when the user opens the screen that will use that table.

Please provide sample code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is to use a DB for local data. If you need them in a rows and columns way then an SQL like databse is your best option. I've use hive before which is a key value data store that is very good and efficient.

I suggest you add the data to the db on the application's first load and then just fetch when ever the user accesses it again.

Here's a good article that shows the difference between the most popular data stores for flutter.

https://blog.codemagic.io/choosing-the-right-database-for-your-flutter-app/